# Need to hardcode according to other domain configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

- I am trying to find the size of the file in another domain
- when I paste the link in the text box  and hit save I need to find the size of the file...now it's working for same domain URL
- so what I am trying to do is hard code the values in my request.
- for example, I hard coded type: "HEAD", to type:'GET' since the other domain was using type GET.
- but now I am getting a new error. is there any way I can hard code domain too
- Can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below.

https://jsfiddle.net/9k1cs9ou/

input http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf

Mixed Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

```
request = $.ajax({
  type: "HEAD",
  crossDomain: true,
  data: JSON.stringify(somejson),
  dataType: "json",

  url: $("#fname").val(),
  success: function () {
    alert("Size is " + request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
    var resp = JSON.parse(response)
            alert(resp.status);
    // 10485760 -10MB
    if(request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length") <= 10485760/2){
      alert(request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length") <= 10485760/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Http access control or `CORS` will prevent access from other domains unless the header is presented on the destination not on origin.

For instance, if you have your app hosted on `www.mysite.com` and you try to fetch a document from `https://stackoverflow.com` it will block your request because your website `www.mysite.com` isn't allowed access ON `https://stackoverflow.com`.

[HTTP Access Control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)